# Accessing SortedList which is the value of another sorted list

Tags: c#, list

This may be an easy question, but I can't find the answer anywhere! As you'll be able to tell, I'm fairly new to coding.

I'm currently working on a project which uses a `SortedList` to store a string value as its key and a second `SortedList` as its value. The second `SortedList` has a series of numeric IDs (though stored as strings) as keys and another string as the value.

I've got no problem entering the values as above, but I'm having trouble accessing the second SortedList which is the value of the first.

I'm tying myself in knots trying to work it out and hope that someone may be able to point me in the right direction.

Sample (simlified) code below...

```
//New and empty SortedLists created
SortedList mySL1 = new SortedList();
SortedList mySL2 = new SortedList();

//Clicking button1 first ensures mySL2 is clear and then adds a couple of KVPs
//Then text entered into a textBox and mySL2 are added as a KVP to mySL1
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mySL2.Clear();
    mySL2.Add("w", "x");
    mySL2.Add("y", "z");

    mySL1.Add(textBox1.Text, mySL2);
}

//Clicking button2 outputs each of the keys of mySL1 to a listBox
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < mySL1.Count; i++)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(mySL1.GetKey(i));
    }
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < mySL1.Count; i++)
    {

        //How do I access the KVPs of the mySL2 SortedLists which are the values of mySL1?

    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I suspect that I've been unclear as to what I was asking and over complicated a fairly simple query by including for loops in my 'simple code'.
What I'm having problems with is the syntax of accessing a list within a list.

Suppose, as in the above example, I have a sorted list (mySL1) of which the value is a second sorted list (mySL2).

The syntax for accessing the key of mySL1 at index 5 is mySL1.GetKey(5)

What I'm trying to find out is the syntax for accessing a particular key or value in mySL2 of a particular index of mySL1, for example the key at index 6 of the mySL2 list which is (the value) at index 5 of mySL1.
As i may want to access specific keys or values from mySL2 a foreach loop won't be sufficient.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  The better tagged your question is, the more visibility it will have.  Start by editing your question to add the tag for your language (I think its `C#`)

Comment: Thanks, and apologies for my poor tagging.

As always seems to be the case in these things after hours of searching and testing without luck, within minutes of posting here I think I might actually have worked it out! I'd still be interested in others' input but will add my findings tomorrow.

Comment: You asked this same question earlier, and appear to have simply deleted it.  You should not be deleting and re-asking the same question.

Comment: I've not deleted anything nor asked earlier. Could it possibly be that someone else asked a similar question or mine was temporarily unavailable while I was editing to add the tag as suggested above?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding this. What is the point of SL1 if it only ever holds a single value?

Comment: Anyway, you probably want the foreach keyword.

Comment: Hi Ben, in practice there would be several KVPs in each list.

Comment: @user2161563 if you could use simple `[]` syntax for your sorted lists instead of the methods, how would you do what you're trying to do? I want to know, because what you're trying to do is still unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## New Answer

Ok, I'm still not entirely sure what the original poster is looking for, but here is my
best guess with the information that I have so far:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfLists.Count; i++)
    {
        var list = (SortedList) listOfLists.GetByIndex(i);

        for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
        {
            var key = (string) list.GetKey(j);
            var value = (string) list.GetByIndex(j);
        }
    }
}
```

You already know how to get the key of your `SortedList` at an index `i` by using [`GetKey(i)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.getkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
You can also get the value at that index by using [`GetByIndex(i)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.getbyindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). All of these can be found in the documentation, I suggest that you always read over it to see if there's anything in there that you can use.

## Old Answer

I'm keeping this answer around in case it may be of use to the original poster.

You can use `foreach` loops to get the values of the 2nd list as KeyValuePairs:

```
var lists = new SortedList<string, SortedList<string, string>>
{
    {
        "foo",
        new SortedList<string, string>
        {
            { "0", "lol" },
            { "1", "skadoosh!" },
            { "2", "OMG!" }
        }
    }
};

foreach (var list in lists)
{
    foreach (var kvp in list.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("({0}, {1})", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }
}
```

#### Prefer Generic Collections to Non-Generic Ones

So, a couple of things to note with the above. I'm using the generic version of `SortedList`, i.e. [`SortedList<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), because you get more type safety checks when accessing values then if you use the [non-generic version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). By using the generic version with explicit typing, you avoid having to explicitly cast types, like you would with the non-generic version ([its methods return type `object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.item%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), like so:

```
var list = new SortedList();
list["foo"] = "bar";
string x = (string) list["foo"];

// vs generic

var list = new SortedList<string, string>();
list["foo"] = "bar";
string x = list["foo"];
```

It's generally best practice to use the generic versions of collections if you can. You should avoid the non-generic collections in most cases, you'll probably only see them in legacy code nowadays.

#### foreach loops with `SortedList<TKey, TValue>`

Okay, so the `foreach` loops allow you to get the values of a collection without having to specify an index or a key. So what are the values of a `SortedList<TKey, TValue>`? The values are `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`:

1. `SortedList<string, SortedList<string, string>>` contains
   `KeyValuePair<string, SortedList<string, string>>`.
2. `SortedList<string, string>` contains `KeyValuePair<string, string>`.

So in the first `foreach` loop, you get `KeyValuePair<string, SortedList<string, string>>`, and you want to access the list which is the value in that pair:

```
foreach (var list in lists)
{
    foreach (var kvp in list.Value)
    {
        // Do stuff with kvp
    }
}
```

So `list.Value` is a `SortedList<string, string>`, which contains `(key, value)` pairs of more strings. So you can just access each key and value with `kvp.Key` and `kvp.Value`.

#### To `var` or not to `var`? That is the question :P

You can also declare your `foreach` loops by specifying the item types explicitly instead of using `var`:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, SortedList<string, string>> list in lists)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in list.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("({0}, {1})", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }
}
```

Which style you choose is up to you, they're both equivalent. Personally, I only use `var` when the type is obvious, otherwise it can be hard to tell what type is being used, especially if you're reviewing the code outside of Visual Studio, like in a Git diff or something. Another downside to using `var` instead of an explicit type is that you then can't declare object instances using interfaces, like this:

```
IDictionary<int, string> players = new SortedList<int, string>
{
    { 0, "John" }, { 1, "Dave" }
};
```

Declaring an object instance with an interface means that you'll be forced to only use methods that that interface declares, which can make it easier for you to switch implementations later. Of course, this is much less verbose:

```
var players = new SortedList<int, string> { { 0, "John" }, { 1, "Dave" } };
```

The use of `var` is a topic that has a history of a lot of debate.

Comment: Thanks Cupcake. I suspect that I've been unclear as to what I was asking (it was the end of a very long day!) and possibly over complicated a fairly simple query by including for loops in my 'simple code'.
What I'm trying to find out is the syntax for accessing a particular key or value in mySL2 of a particular index of mySL1, for example the key at index 6 of the mySL2 list which is (the value) at index 5 of mySL1.
As i may want to access specific keys or values from mySL2 a foreach loop won't be sufficient.

Comment: @user2161563 so did my answer not help you? There can be many ways to access a list, it can depend on what kind of lists you're using. Any collection that implements the `IList` interface can be accessed simply like this `list[index]`, so if you have an `IList` of `IList`s, you access the inner lists with `list[index][sub-index]`. But `SortedList` doesn't implement `IList`, it implements `IDictionary`. The concrete class itself can be accessed using indices with its methods, but it's not as simple as normal list indexing with `[]`.

Comment: Your answer has helped a little, it's certainly got me thinking about how I'm doing things and what kind of list I'm using. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @user2161563 updated my answer, is it what you were looking for?

Comment: @user2161563 when you get enough reputation to upvote, please consider upvoting my question if you found it to be helpful, because the points really help me out a lot! :)

Comment: Thanks Cupcake, that's exactly what I needed. Sorry that my question was unclear and thanks for your patience.